Использование классов в Python
занимаюсь изучением классов в Python.
Заметил что в сложных библиотеках в функции __init__ указываются атрибуты например будет работать определённый функционал или нет.
class MyClass:
    
    def __init__(self, is_work):
        self.is_work = is_work
    
    def some_function(self):
        for i in range(10):
            print(i, end=' ')
    
    def function(self):
        if self.is_work:
            print('Working')
        self.some_function()
        
cl  = MyClass(True)

cl.function()

Насколько оптимально в делать проверку в функции через условие (пример function(self))?

спокойно можешь делать так, если по условиям подходит, если нет то лучше писать условия в том же методе который зависит от этого условия (Принцип единственной ответственности)
